# Criar um sistema de log

Tags: php

Bom o sistema padrão de log do php não me atende 100%.

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de quando ocorrer um erro no php, eu preciso salvar um log e alguns valores que estão em, algumas variáveis.

Eu já sei como criar e escrever o arquivo txt, o que eu preciso e como identificar que ocorreu um erro no php?

Comment: Ja deu uma olhada no monolog? https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode fazer isso extendendo a [classe Exception do PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.exception.php)

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

class customException extends Exception
  {
  public function errorMessage()
    {
    //error message
    $errorMsg = 'Erro na linha '.$this->getLine().' do arquivo '.$this->getFile()
    .': <b>'.$this->getMessage().'</b>';
    return $errorMsg;
    }
  }
```